# Retain Form Search values in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on a web application using Spring MVC 4.

I have a search page. Once its submitted, a search results page appears. I have a link (**Revise Search**) on the search results page that will bring users back to the search page.

I am trying to display the search form with the search criteria that the user had originally typed but the @ModelAttribute object holding the search request params is null.

Here's relevant parts of my controller and view (jsp) code

```
@Controller
public class MySearchController extends MyController {

@Autowired
SearchService searchService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(Model model,
        @ModelAttribute("searchParams") SearchParams searchParams,
        BindingResult bindingResult) throws Exception {

    model.addAttribute("city", searchParams.getCity());
    model.addAttribute("zip", searchParams.getZip());

    return "search.def";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/submitSearch")
public String submitSearch(Model model,@Valid @ModelAttribute("searchParams") SearchParams searchParams, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) 
                throws Exception{

    // perform Search
    List searchResults = searchService.find(searchParams.getCity(), searchParams.getZip());
    model.addAttribute("searchResults", searchResults);
    model.addAttribute("searchParams", searchParams);

    return "results.def";
}
```

}

search.def will map to search.jsp

```
<form:form action="submitSearch" modelAttribute="searchParams" method="GET" id="userSearchForm" >
        <table id="search" class="display" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="60%" valign="top">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="name">
                <td><label for="city">City:</label></td> 
                <td><form:input id="city" path="city" type="text" /></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr id="age">
                <td><label for="zip"><br/>Zip:</label></td> 
                <td><form:input type="text" path="zip" /> </td>
            </tr>

    </table>
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Search" > <br/>
    </form:form>
```

results.def will map to results.jsp

```
<div class="resultHeader">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="search">Revise search</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<table id="resultsBody" class="display" valign="top" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr id="results_header" class="thhead">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Identifier</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="result" items="${searchResults}" varStatus="rowNum">
            <td><c:out value="${result.customerName}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out  value="${result.customerType}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out  value="${result.customerIdentifier}"></c:out></td></tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
  < /table>


 </div>
```

Now, when I click the **Revise Search** link in the results page, the searchParams object always remains null. How can I retain the original values? @ModelAttribute, I guess is only request scope. Do I have to add it to pass the search params one by one as a request param? /search is a GET and I do not want the search parameters cluttering the url. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `@ModelAttribute` only binds values from post parameters. Your 'revise search' link is a GET request to `/search` which never included any values of `searchParameters`.

You need some mechanism of persisting searchParameters accross requests, for example [using HttpSession (`@SessionAttributes` annotation)](https://gerrydevstory.com/2014/03/04/using-sessionattribute-in-spring-mvc-to-implement-a-shopping-cart/)

Comment: Thanks @gerrytan My application also has another search form with similar values. I am wondering if I can use it as a session object. I will then have to clear out the values, every time, user switches from one form to another. I will try and let you know

Comment: If you have found a solution, can you please share it ?